# Get JSON object in categories JSON

Tags: php, json

```
{
 meta: {}
 notifications: []
 response: {}
}
```

FULL JSON = https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4c6397fbec94a5937d472cca/tips?sort=recent&oauth_token=QABX2VQDBCHYJOHYQUGMNMBBA3KZY41YOOVNT5MY1OFYFYNA&v=20140703

```
$asObjects = json_decode($json);

foreach ($asObjects as $obj) 
{
    echo $obj->response->text;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This method do not work because text in `response : {}` how can i get text ?

Comment: try print_r($asObjects) and see what your getting

Comment: If you don't know what you are working with, you should use print_r() as @ArunKumarM has suggested to see what's inside the object.

Comment: Your `response` object is empty.  What's *really* in it?

Comment: Editted my text guys you can check full JSON with link

Comment: It is often easier to manipulate the json data as arrays rather than objects. I use 'json_decode($json, true);' which converts objects to php arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your full json, you need to iterate on the items array and then show the text for each item :

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($json);

foreach ($jsonObj->response->tips->items as $obj) 
{
    echo $obj->text;
    echo "<br>";
}
```